# Integer - toString() function

Tags: java

I search but cannot find on the web.

Is there a function that can represent any integer into its String litteral representation ?

Example :

```
Integer i1 = new Integer(4);
Integer i2 = new Integer(30);
i1.callSomeFunction();
i2.callSomeFunction();

Output :
"Four"
"Thirty"
```

If you know another function which isn't in the Integer class, it's fine too.

Comment: In which language(s)?

Comment: And, don't use `new Integer(x)`, always use `Integer.of(x)`.

Comment: @Pshemo It will give "1", not "one"

Comment: @Neet: `Integer.valueOf(…)`. But its even easier to do the same: `Integer i1 =  4, i2 = 30; `

Comment: @Holger of course, but as this is an explicit assignment to a boxed type, one should use the correct boxed type creation or use an `int` right away IMHO.

Comment: @zakinster Thanks, you cant put this a an answer, I will accept

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard method to do this but take a look at [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0426.html). There is an example for a number to words in the English language converter.